# How to optimize checking process between defined locations

Tags: java, android, algorithm, location, mathematical-optimization

I am a bit inexperienced programmer. I am working on an android project which will play specific video in some cases. My client have defined some square zones on a map which my app saves these zones in database. Each zone has four components : Min and Max of Lat and Lng. I keep track of the current location of the user via GPS(and offline). My goal is to check if the user is inside one of defined zones, if yes video will be played, else nothing. This checking process should be done every second so it must be optimized. my question is : what is the best algorithm ? How to implement this algorithm in order to check between zones as fast as possible ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service like this

```
public class YourService extends Service {

private final static String TAG = "yourtag";
public static final String YOURTIMEOUT = "com.example.timeout";
public static final String TIMER = "com.example.timer";
private Intent bi = new Intent(YOURTIMEOUT );
private CountDownTimer cdt = null;



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(YOURTIMEOUT );
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

private void newCountdown() {

   cdt = new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            sendBroadcast(bi);
        }
    };
    cdt.start();
}

private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        switch (intent.getAction()) {
            case YOURTIMEOUT :
                newCountdown();
                break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    cdt.cancel();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    newCountdown();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

Obviously this is every second so there's no point for the countdown, but if you decide to change the every second part then it comes quite handy.

Get your interested activity to catch the intent with YOURTIMEOUT tag and run your checking code when you get it. Make sure to stop the service when your activity goes on pause.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I think you didnot get the point exactly. My question is not how to create service, my question is the checking algorithm itself ! how can I optimizely check the current location with many locations already defined in database every sec ?